# are two threads involved when use APM BeginXX, EndXXX methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, threadpool

For example, we have the following APM APIs:

```
public virtual IAsyncResult BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, object state);
public virtual WebResponse EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
```

so when I call `BeginGetResponse` in the main thread, I outlines the sequences below, correct me if I'm wrong

1-the main thread enqueue the request work on the thread pool.

2-some times later, thread pool assign a thread to send the request.Then this thread is recycled back into thread pool.

3-Once all the data arrives, the thread pool assign a new thread to process the result, we can call `EndGetResponse` in this thread to get the result.

So apart from the main thread,  there are two new threads involved to get the job done, is my understanding correct? If yes, are those new threads all I/O threads, or the first one is a IO thread and the second thread is a worker thread?

Edit:

Below is the quote from my textbook:

**A far more efficient approach(i.e use BeginXXX and EndXXX) would be to create a thread to request the data from the web server, give the thread back to the thread pool, and when the data arrives, obtain a thread from the pool to process the results.**

Comment: Pretty unclear what the textbook is trying to teach you.  It doesn't take a thread to get the request started.  There is a physical thread, but it is a kernel thread that's buried in the TCP/IP driver stack.  Nothing you can do, or want to do, to alter the way it works.  It is by virtue of this driver thread that no .NET thread is needed.  The framework documentation does however point out that it prefers to have a worker thread call BeginGetResponse() because it can't guarantee how long it takes.  Which is panicky, but helps to get customers with a lousy DNS server off the support phone call.

Comment: @Hans Passant  so do you mean the main thread get the request started? so what happened after the main thread call `BeginXXX` method?

Comment: Hopefully it does something else useful, the only reason to use BeginXxxx.  The main thread of a GUI app is by far the most typical scenario.  If it doesn't do anything useful but just waits for the request to complete then it shouldn't use APM since that just adds unnecessary overhead.  The main thread of a console app being the most typical case.

Answer (score 0):

> I outlines the sequences below, correct me if I'm wrong

Sorry, but you are wrong. :)

> 1-the main thread enqueue the request work on the thread pool

No. As a general rule, the only time a method of the form `BeginXXX()` queues something to the thread pool is the `BeginInvoke()` method on a delegate type.

Otherwise, the usual implementation (on Windows) is to use "I/O Completion Ports" (IOCP). This will eventually result in your callback method being executed on a thread from the IOCP thread pool, but at step #1 the only thing that happens is that the I/O operation is initiated, associating it with an I/O completion port.

> 2-some times later, thread pool assign a thread to send the request.Then this thread is recycled back into thread pool.

This step never happens.

> 3-Once all the data arrives, the thread pool assign a new thread to process the result, we can call EndGetResponse in this thread to get the result.

This step is the only step at which a thread pool thread executes code. And to be clear: the thread is in the IOCP thread pool, not the regular thread pool.

What happens is that when the original I/O operation was initiated, the underlying native Windows call associated the I/O completion port with it. The port is a feature in the native Windows API that allows Windows to wake up a thread in the thread pool automatically when the I/O operation completes. This executes some .NET code, which then in turn executes your code to finally resolve the operation.

There are exceptions, of course. There is nothing enforcing the above for classes that implement the `BeginXXX()/EndXXX()` pattern. But this is invariably how .NET components will implement it. And since for third-party components that implement it, they will typically not be calling the native API directly, but instead will be using some .NET IO object (typically a `FileStream`, `Socket`, or some other class that ultimately depends on one of those two classes), even they will also wind up using IOCP as the underlying implementation.

Note that there is one other prominent exception, where neither the thread pool nor IOCP is used: the `BeginInvoke()` methods for Winforms or WPF/Dispatcher-based code. These, of course, queue your delegate for invocation on a *specific* non-thread-pool thread. This is more similar to the thread-pool scenario, but technically is not that, and would still only involve a single thread in any case.

Comment: So what does `BeginXXX()` actually do? I also quoted what the author says in the post, could you have a look please? It did mentioned that two threads are involved asd : 1-create a thread to request the data from the web server  2. when the data arrives, obtain a thread from the pool to process the results. So two threads involved, which contradicts what you said?

Comment: You would have to ask the author of the book to explain why they wrote what they did. It's not unheard of for people to write books without fully understanding the topic, or for them to write books without being careful about how they express a concept, or even for editors of such books to accidentally modify the content in ways that conflict with the author's intent. If you want to know what `BeginGetResponse()` actually does, you can look here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,613ffcf7266252eb. Though...

Comment: ...it's pretty convoluted code, due to all the machinations required to handle both async and synchronous operations in the same methods, as well as deal with various HTTP implementations (particularly whether or not a connection needs to be re-established on each request). You might have better luck following the code flow for more basic I/O like for a `FileStream` or `Socket` (though, these too have a lot of special-case logic in them as well).

Comment: The bottom line: there is no inherent need to create a thread in order to request data from a server. Short requests should be able to be posted immediately, with the only asynchronous aspect being waiting for the response. That said, one might find some asynchronous aspect when posting the request, if it involves uploading a lot of data. But even there, it will follow the IOCP model: the actual operation is initiated without queuing any thread pool operation; an IOCP thread will be used to handle completion of the operation, which might include sending more data, or just wait for the response

Comment: @secondimage - Stephen Cleary write [There is no Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) discussing the Task Asynchronous Pattern, but the same kind of things also happen with the APM.

Answer (score 0):

`BeginXXX`/`EndXXX` is just a pattern (one of) which is used to describe asynchronous execution semantic. How it actually behaves in any specific case depends on actual implementation of the pattern. Most of I/O-bound scenarios covered by .NET Framework use IOCP underneath, which implies that they don't use any additional thread to issue an I/O request to completion port, and as soon as the asynchronous I/O was primary target of the pattern usage in pre-async age we tended to think about it as something with no thread. However the scope of areas where IOCP can be applied is limited by internal file handles mechanism which covers mostly file sytem objects, sockets, named pipes and maybe couple of other objects (all of them related to the I/O scenarios). For the rest scenarios (as an asynchrony can be not only I/O-bound) an implementation can be different and using a thread as an option to initiate an asynchronous execution cannot be excluded. As for the example referred in the book, the `BeginGetResponse` and `EnGetResponse` methods of `HttpWebRequest` class (unless some other type is implied) are built on top of .NET streams APM API which internally uses IOCP, so they are IOCP-based and no thread is created when `BeginGetResponse` is invoked. So answer to the:

> are two threads involved when use APM BeginXX, EndXXX methods?

comes down to two options:

- In general case it depends in the implementation.
- In specific case you provided as an example no thread is created for `BeginGetResponse` as well as any other IOCP-based implementation.